# Possible to have 2.8 mirror modifier scaling work as in 2.78?

Tags: modifiers, mirror, scale, 3d-cursor, origin

When scaling an edge loop of half of a mesh with mirror modifier enabled, in blender 2.79 it would scale assuming the center of the loop region was the center of the whole mesh. This isn't the case anymore, is it possible to bring this behavior back?

I am aware of setting the pivot point using the `.` key, but is there really no setting for "How it was before"? I don't want to have to position the 3D cursor every time I want to scale an edge loop around the true center of that individual edge loop.

This is a similar question to [Mirror modifier changes behaviour of scaling 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143291/mirror-modifier-changes-behaviour-of-scaling-2-8) but the answer to that does not fully resolve my particular issue.

[image: Expected behavior circa 2.78]

[image: Behavior circa 2.8]

Comment: Hi. I can't replicate that behaviour. In both 2.79 and 2.82 the scaling doesn't take into account the mirror modifier unless I choose a different pivot point. Unless you just need to turn clipping on on the mirror modifier?

Comment: I'm specificially talking about the scaling of an edge loop (simply hitting S and dragging) when a mesh has the mirror modifier enabled
https://www.dropbox.com/s/efdfh0ivk4j8b5h/1.PNG?dl=0

in 2.78, I would get this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhhndlwyp4zepun/2.PNG?dl=0

but in 2.8 I'm getting this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xp65au2v4qk3bv/3.PNG?dl=0